# Android Bottom White Stripe When Filling Webview Content

Tags: java, android, eclipse, html, jquery-mobile

Once an HTML is loaded in to a webview, I get a white stripe on the right and bottom of the layout. For the right one I solved it using:

`setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);`

However, I have tried many options to remove the bottom one with no success. Even after I read all the related posts. If more code is required please let me know.

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<WebView android:autoLink="web" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/webview1" 
     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
     ></WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity**

```
browse = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
browse.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browse.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
browse.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browse.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
browse.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: May be it is device specific problem? On my device and on the emulator I don't get white stripes even without `SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY` (I use your code and load random site). What device do you use? P.S. May be you are doing anything else with WebView?

Comment: I agree, I also can see it without stripes on simulator but not on device. Phone model Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo, android 2.3.4

Comment: It might be a problem with the web viewer and the html structure and properties of the page that you're viewing. For example viewing a html with a 2 img structured like this: table->tr->td->img->tr->td->img. When using google chrome the page is rendered normally while in firefox 8-11 a white stripe will appear. it may also be caused by auto margin which is default in a paragraph tag which is also not rendered properly in your webviewer. Uhh, well you can always try.

Comment: @Jaume i agree your statement iam also faceing same issue white space in Sony Ericsson Xperia  without stripes on simulator.How to solve this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your WebView xml, add android:scrollbars="none"

```
<WebView android:autoLink="web" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/webview1" 
 android:textColor="@android:color/black"
 android:scrollbars="none"
 ></WebView>
```

And remove the `setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);`

Answer (score 0):

For me the bottom white stripe disappeared after adding:

`browse.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);`

The accepted solution didn't work for me (API 8).