# Android: Webview load URL with a white stripe at the bottom

Tags: android, webview

I build a Webview like this:

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    </WebView>
```

And if i go to a Website all work. But some sites got loades with a white stripe at the bottom, which covers the half or 3/4 of the webview.

I saw: [Android Bottom White Stripe When Filling Webview Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708220/android-bottom-white-stripe-when-filling-webview-content)

so i changed my WebView to:

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    </WebView>
```

But this didnt helps. I get the white stripe again and again.

Comment: Have you tried to use "match_parent" and remove the align parts?

Comment: @Carnal Thank you for help, this was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution from Carnal:  use "match_parent" remove "align parts"

I edited my code to:

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView2"
        >

    </WebView>
```

And now it works!